# How to do video chat using webrtc in angular8

Tags: css, angular, typescript, webrtc

Hello I am trying to integrate video chat between two users in angular 8 Using webRTC but I am unable to do that.Is there any suggestion how will i do that in angula8 please help me out.

**component.html**

```
<div class="videoCall">

 <video #localVideo class="self" playsinline autoplay></video>
<video #remoteVideo class="self" style="margin-left: 10px;" playsinline autoplay></video>
</div>
<div>
      <button #startButton [disabled]="startButtonDisabled" (click)="start()">Start</button>
      <button #callButton [disabled]="callButtonDisabled" (click)="call()">Call</button>
      <button #hangupButton [disabled]="hangupButtonDisabled" (click)="hangup()">Hang Up</button>
</div>
```

**componenet.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import * as signalR from "@aspnet/signalr";
import { VideoCallService } from '../../common/services/video-call.service';
// import{ConnectionManager} from '../right-connect/connectionManager.component';
import adapter from 'webrtc-adapter';

@Component({
  selector: 'right-connect',
  templateUrl: './right-connect.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./right-connect.component.scss']
})



export class RightConnectComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('startButton', {static: false}) startButton: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('callButton', {static: false}) callButton: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('hangupButton', {static: false}) hangupButton: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('localVideo', {static: false}) localVideo: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('remoteVideo', {static: false}) remoteVideo: ElementRef;

  startButtonDisabled = false;
  callButtonDisabled = true;
  hangupButtonDisabled = true;

  startTime;
  localStream;
  pc1;
  pc2;
  offerOptions = {
    offerToReceiveAudio: 1,

    offerToReceiveVideo: 1
  };

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.localVideo.nativeElement.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', ()=> {
  this.trace('Local video videoWidth: ' + this.localVideo.nativeElement.videoWidth +
    'px,  videoHeight: ' + this.localVideo.nativeElement.videoHeight + 'px');
});

this.remoteVideo.nativeElement.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', ()=> {
  this.trace('Remote video videoWidth: ' + this.remoteVideo.nativeElement.videoWidth +
    'px,  videoHeight: ' + this.remoteVideo.nativeElement.videoHeight + 'px');
});

this.remoteVideo.nativeElement.onresize = ()=> {
  this.trace('Remote video size changed to ' +
    this.remoteVideo.nativeElement.videoWidth + 'x' + this.remoteVideo.nativeElement.videoHeight);


};
  }

  getName(pc) {
    return (pc === this.pc1) ? 'pc1' : 'pc2';
  }

  getOtherPc(pc) {
    return (pc === this.pc1) ? this.pc2 : this.pc1;
  }

  gotStream(stream) {
    this.trace('Received local stream');
    this.localVideo.nativeElement.srcObject = stream;
    this.localStream = stream;
    this.callButtonDisabled = false;
  }

  start() {
    this.trace('Requesting local stream');
    this.startButtonDisabled = true;
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: true,
      video: true
    })
    .then(this.gotStream.bind(this))
    .catch(function(e) {
      console.log('error', e);
      alert('getUserMedia() error: ' + e.name);
    });
  }

  call() {
    this.callButtonDisabled = true;
    this.hangupButtonDisabled = false;
    this.trace('Starting call');
    this.startTime = window.performance.now();
    var videoTracks = this.localStream.getVideoTracks();
    var audioTracks = this.localStream.getAudioTracks();
    if (videoTracks.length > 0) {
      this.trace('Using video device: ' + videoTracks[0].label);
    }
    if (audioTracks.length > 0) {
      this.trace('Using audio device: ' + audioTracks[0].label);
    }
    var servers =  {'iceServers': [{'urls': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'}]};
    this.pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
    this.trace('Created local peer connection object pc1');
    /*this.pc1.onicecandidate = e => {
      this.onIceCandidate(this.pc1, e);
    };*/
    this.pc1.addEventListener('icecandidate', (e: Event) => {
            this.onIceCandidate(this.pc1, e);
    });
    this.pc2 = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
    this.trace('Created remote peer connection object pc2');
    /*this.pc2.onicecandidate = e => {
      this.onIceCandidate(this.pc2, e);
    };*/
    this.pc2.addEventListener('icecandidate', (e: Event) => {
      this.onIceCandidate(this.pc2, e);
    });
    /*this.pc1.oniceconnectionstatechange = e => {
      this.onIceStateChange(this.pc1, e);
    };
    this.pc2.oniceconnectionstatechange = e => {
      this.onIceStateChange(this.pc2, e);
    };*/
    this.pc1.addEventListener('iceconnectionstatechange', (e: Event) => {
            this.onIceStateChange(this.pc1, e);
    });
    this.pc2.addEventListener('iceconnectionstatechange', (e: Event) => {
            this.onIceStateChange(this.pc2, e);
    });
    this.pc2.ontrack = this.gotRemoteStream.bind(this);

    this.localStream.getTracks().forEach(
      track => {
        this.trace('add tracks to pc1');
        this.pc1.addTrack(
          track,
          this.localStream
        );
      }
    );
    this.trace('Added local stream to pc1');

    this.trace('pc1 createOffer start');
    this.pc1.createOffer(
      this.offerOptions
    ).then(
      this.onCreateOfferSuccess.bind(this),
      this.onCreateSessionDescriptionError.bind(this)
    );
  }

  onCreateSessionDescriptionError(error) {
    this.trace('Failed to create session description: ' + error.toString());
  }

  onCreateOfferSuccess(desc) {
    this.trace('Offer from pc1\n' + desc.sdp);
    this.trace('pc1 setLocalDescription start');
    this.pc1.setLocalDescription(desc).then(
      () => {
        this.onSetLocalSuccess(this.pc1);
      },
      this.onSetSessionDescriptionError.bind(this)
    );
    this.trace('pc2 setRemoteDescription start');
    this.pc2.setRemoteDescription(desc).then(
      () => {
        this.onSetRemoteSuccess(this.pc2);
      },
      this.onSetSessionDescriptionError.bind(this)
    );
    this.trace('pc2 createAnswer start');
    // Since the 'remote' side has no media stream we need
    // to pass in the right constraints in order for it to
    // accept the incoming offer of audio and video.
    this.pc2.createAnswer().then(
      this.onCreateAnswerSuccess.bind(this),
      this.onCreateSessionDescriptionError.bind(this)
    );
  }

  onSetLocalSuccess(pc) {
    this.trace(this.getName(pc) + ' setLocalDescription complete');
  }

  onSetRemoteSuccess(pc) {
    this.trace(this.getName(pc) + ' setRemoteDescription complete');
  }

  onSetSessionDescriptionError(error) {
    this.trace('Failed to set session description: ' + error.toString());
  }

  gotRemoteStream(e) {
    if (this.remoteVideo.nativeElement.srcObject !== e.streams[0]) {
      this.remoteVideo.nativeElement.srcObject = e.streams[0];
      this.trace('pc2 received remote stream');
    }
  }

  onCreateAnswerSuccess(desc) {
    this.trace('Answer from pc2:\n' + desc.sdp);
    this.trace('pc2 setLocalDescription start');
    this.pc2.setLocalDescription(desc).then(
      () => {
        this.onSetLocalSuccess(this.pc2);
      },
      this.onSetSessionDescriptionError.bind(this)
    );
    this.trace('pc1 setRemoteDescription start');
    this.pc1.setRemoteDescription(desc).then(
      () => {
        this.onSetRemoteSuccess(this.pc1);
      },
      this.onSetSessionDescriptionError.bind(this)
    );
  }

  onIceCandidate(pc, event) {
    this.getOtherPc(pc).addIceCandidate(event.candidate)
    .then(
      () => {
        this.onAddIceCandidateSuccess(pc);
      },
      (err) => {
        this.onAddIceCandidateError(pc, err);
      }
    );
    this.trace(this.getName(pc) + ' ICE candidate: \n' + (event.candidate ?
        event.candidate.candidate : '(null)'));
  }

  onAddIceCandidateSuccess(pc) {
    this.trace(this.getName(pc) + ' addIceCandidate success');
  }

  onAddIceCandidateError(pc, error) {
    this.trace(this.getName(pc) + ' failed to add ICE Candidate: ' + error.toString());
  }

  onIceStateChange(pc, event) {
    if (pc) {
      this.trace(this.getName(pc) + ' ICE state: ' + pc.iceConnectionState);
      console.log('ICE state change event: ', event);
    }
  }

  hangup() {
    this.trace('Ending call');
    this.pc1.close();
    this.pc2.close();
    this.pc1 = null;
    this.pc2 = null;
    this.hangupButtonDisabled = true;
    this.callButtonDisabled = false;
  }

  trace(arg) {
    var now = (window.performance.now() / 1000).toFixed(3);
    console.log(now + ': ', arg);
  }
}
```

component.scss

```
.videoCall{
    display: flex;
    .self{

        width: 264px;
        height: 298px;
        border: 2px solid black;
    }
    .partner{

margin-left: 10px;
        width: 264px;
        height: 298px;
        border: 2px solid black;
    }
}
```

I am unable to call between two users. how will I do that. Or is there any other way to integrate video call in angualr 8 please suggest me. Please help me out
Thanks